# how to have date time column converted into date and displaying as 103 style

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi i've a column the_date which is having sample data like 
`1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
1990-01-01 00:00:00.000
1990-01-02 00:00:00.000
1990-01-03 00:00:00.000
1990-01-04 00:00:00.000
1990-01-05 00:00:00.000
1990-01-06 00:00:00.000
1990-01-07 00:00:00.000`

now i just want to select only date only and displaying it into 103 style and convert the column into Date format. i've tried this syntax`convert(varchar,THE_DATE , 103)` but then the column is not in Date format.
any help please.

Comment: Formatting is NOT done in the database, it is done in the front end. The date datatype is not stored in some format. It is stored as a number in the database.

Comment: sorry then maybe i've not expressed myself clearly, i'd like to convert the column into date and portrait the result into 103 style.

Answer (score 1):

This Works try it once

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar,CAST(DATE_TIME AS DATE),103)AS Date_Time From <yourTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little confusing because regardless of the datatype, you will always get the same answer with `CONVERT`.  I'll illustrate this with 2 declared variables, 1 datetime datatype, the other date datatype:

```
DECLARE @mydatetime datetime = '1990-01-01 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @mydate date = '1900-01-01'

SELECT convert(varchar,@mydatetime, 103) as mydatetime
SELECT convert(varchar,@mydate, 103) as mydate
```

Produces:

```
mydatetime
01/01/1990

mydate
01/01/1900
```

So you don't need to cast to date, then to 103 format.

If you don't like the time with date in your table (datetime) then you can always ALTER the column in the table to the date datatype.  This can be done using SSMS or you can do the SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn DATE
```

Where `DATE` is the new datatype.  And then only the date is stored in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a string (or an equivalent database type) to another type is called "parsing". Converting another type to string is called "formatting".

The `DATE` or `DATETIME` type (or equivalent type in the front-end) does not store dates as string and has therefore no format. A number is used to represent the date internally which counts the days since a reference date (1753-01-01 for SQL-Server). The time is represented as decimal fraction. 
Of course you always see the date as formatted when you open the table, because it is converted to a text for display, but it is not stored as formatted.

So, what you have to do if your date is given as text, is to parse it using the 121 format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.MMM (24h)) to get a `DATE` (or `DATETIME`).

```
CONVERT(DATE, the_date, 121)      or      CONVERT(DATETIME, the_date, 121)
```

If `the_date` is already of `DATE` (or `DATETIME`) type and you want to display it in the 103 format (DD/MM/YYYY)

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), the_date, 103)
```

---

If the date is given as `DATETIME` type and you just want to strip off the time part and return the result as `DATETIME` type again, you can do

```
DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, the_date ), 0)
```

Note that no date format is involved here, since the date does never appear as text.

Comment: HI, yeah my column is in datetime format and i've triend this DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, the_date ), 0) just to strip off time part, but it's not working. it is still giving me the result with time part.

Comment: You must make the difference between changing the datetime value and formatting the datetime value for display. For display don't change the datetime value in the db, but convert it to a text by formatting it appropriately, i.e. only temporarily. The display is always of a text format. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql. And usually the formatting happens in the front-end (the application), not in the back-end (db, sql).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your answer but for anyone who has my same query i got the solution from here 
  [solution](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/13/format-date-sql-server.aspx)